# How to parse JSON with another json inside in java?

Tags: java, json, jackson

This is my JSON:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "username": "bigglesworth",
      "phone": "650-253-0000",
      "createdAt": "2011-11-07T20:58:06.445Z",
      "updatedAt": "2011-11-07T20:58:06.445Z",
      "objectId": "3KmCvT7Zsb"
    },
    {
      "username": "cooldude6",
      "phone": "415-369-6201",
      "createdAt": "2011-11-07T20:58:34.448Z",
      "updatedAt": "2011-11-07T21:25:10.623Z",
      "objectId": "g7y9tkhB7O"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I parse this json?
When I tried to parse this using `jason` I retrived this error message

> "Exception in thread "main"
>
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
> deserialize  instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT
> token"

Comment: Edit your question and add the code you are using to deserialize this JSON

Comment: if you are not using jackson, why the tag??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without third party libraries, you can do something like

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonAsString);
JSONArray results = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
for(int i=0; i<results.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject result = results.getJSONObject(i);
    String username = result.getString("username");
    //...
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! In Java SE there isn't  JSONObject this is only in Java EE. I download org.json in http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20150729